# Data not displaying in jinja

Tags: python, postgresql

This is a piece of code in my flask app for displaying ledger transactions.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    notes = db.execute("SELECT date, note, amount, type FROM customerdb")
    total = sum(notes)
    return render_template("index.html", total = total, notes = notes)
```

this is the function that sums the credit and debit. Credit will be postive and debit is negative.

```
def sum(note):
    total = 0
    for i in note:
        total += i[2]

    return total
```

When I pass only the notes variable to the HTML the table is working but when I pass the total variable along with the notes only the total variable works table is not showing any data.

```html
<p>total: {{total}}</p>
```

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Note</th>
        <th scope="col" id="th1">Credit</th>
        <th scope="col" id="th2">Debit</th>

    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for i in notes %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{i[0]}}</td>
        <td>{{i[1]}}</td>
        {% if(i[3] == 1) %}
            <td headers="th1">{{i[2]}}</td>
            <td headers="th2"></td>
        {% elif(i[3] == 2) %}
            <td headers="th1"></td>
            <td headers="th2">{{i[2]}}</td>
        {% endif %}
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
```

Table without passing total variable in:
[image]

Table after passing total variable:
[image]

Comment: note that `sum` is also a builtin function, try giving your own one a different name.

Comment: Share all the code from this html page, i will help us spot the mistake

Comment: @IstvanSzekeres changed it still not working

Comment: @Reznik I did literally everything. This is the whole content inside my body tag.

Comment: i run same code which you trying i am able to get ouput. Only instead of sql result i used constant list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fetchall()` at the end of the notes variable worked.

Comment: means you have issue at your result set. Code works well. Right ?

Comment: @aviboy2006 yep it works. What is the problem though I can't figure it out.

Comment: The problem is that the cursor is an iterator and not a concrete list; once you'd iterated through it for `sum()`, it's exhausted and has no more items. `.fetchall()`, or casting it into a `list()`, will make it concrete, at the expense of actually needing to have all those items in memory.